# How to set the code to update the table in database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm making a system by using Visual Studio Express 2012 and use the Microsoft SQL Server that already have in visual studio I think. My problem is, when i'm trying to run my system,an error occur said "Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'." This is my code.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Registration
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user_PC\Desktop\For FYP\Computer Lab Requirement System\FYP3\FYP3\FYP.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Private Sub Registration_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cmd.Connection = cn
    End Sub

Private Sub btnRegisterL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegisterL.Click
    If txtIDL.Text <> "" And txtUsernameL.Text <> "" And txtPasswordL.Text <> "" Then
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "update info set id = '" & txtIDL.Text & "',user = '" & txtUsernameL.Text & "',pass = '" & txtPasswordL.Text & "'where id =  '" & Form1.DataGridView1 & "' "
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        txtIDL.Text = ""
        txtUsernameL.Text = ""
        txtPasswordL.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm glad if there is some one could help me to explain and teach me about whats wrong with my coding above. I'm new in this thing. Thanks. :)

Comment: datagridview1 .. you should tell the cell .. because datagridview1 is not string ..

Comment: i can't understand.. could u please explain to me how to do that ? thanks..

Comment: like this .. `Form1.DataGridView1.rows(0).cells("code").value.ToString` ..

Comment: You need to [parameterize your query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/).

Answer (score 0):

You could hold the Primary Key of your data in your GridView in one of the columns and then use that in your query, instead of the below line that you have:

```
 "'where id =  '" & Form1.DataGridView1 & "' "
```